# Removing libraries compiles project fine?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When I was programming my project I introduced various libraries by moving them to my `/libs` folder and telling Gradle to compile them. Now I've noticed that even if I remove the lines for their compilation from Grade, the project still compiles and works fine.

Why? What was the point of adding them into my Gradle dependencies if I don't need them?

Comment: Maybe you code doesn't use them, why did you add them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few cases I can think of:

1. Some of the dependencies you introduced later on were in turn dependent on the ones you removed. Gradle would download all the dependent libraries and so your project might be working fine.
2. There could be runtime dependencies on those libraries. So, removing them doesn't affect the compilation but, it might fail if someone invokes a code which depends on the library and you might see a NoClassDefFoundError
3. Your project used to depend on those libraries earlier but now it doesn't, so removing them doesn't cause any harm.
4. You added those libraries without actually checking if they were needed

Frankly speaking, all I can do is make some random guesses.

Comment: Yep, looks like 1 was it.